# Problem with RTL in Google Docs preview in android

Tags: android, google-apps-script

When I try to make a text right to left in Google Docs, its preview in every android browser, when someone doesn't login, is not OK. I mean an Android browser still shows it in left to right format.
Of course after logging in, or when using the Google Docs Android app, there is no such problem.
Is there a solution for this problem, for example using a Google Apps Script or so?

I tried this code some friend suggested, but it doesn't work properly!

```
function makeRight(){
    var body =DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    console.log("HERE BM!")
    //var paraghraphs = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH);
    for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++){
        var ithchild = body.getChild(i)
        if (ithchild.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH){
            ithchild.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to run your for statement on body.length but this doesn't return a number, so the for statement isn't even running.

I took your code and made some changes then tested on a Google Doc of my own,  the below code seems to work as you're expecting.

```
function makeRight() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var numChildren = body.getNumChildren(); //gets number of children for body

  //for each child of body, run the below code
  for (var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
    var ithchild = body.getChild(i).asParagraph();
    if (ithchild.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      ithchild.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of trying to run the code for "body.length", instead I've defined "numChildren" which gets the number of children for the whole document and returns this as an integer:

```
var numChildren = body.getNumChildren(); //gets number of children for body
```

You also need to get variable "ithchild" as a paragraph, which is why I added asParagraph() to that line:

```
var ithchild = body.getChild(i).asParagraph();
```

This can then be used to run your for statement on the whole document:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
I mean when I run the code, document texts seems right (right to left) on Android browser, but Left to Right on PC browsers!!!
These two platforms, shows same texts in opposite directions! In other words, Android browsers show a Right to Left directed Right aligned texts, Left aligned!!!
Is there a solusion?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to explain, are you able to take some screenshots comparing the two and add them to your post for extra information?

Comment: Of course!...
Thanks.
These are the screenshots:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T3NUstbtBg0u_qFhuL_bzq-L7lPBXrQd/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tTcuL3em7btY8076AevLHFDYKdFUI04g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, try the solution in [this document](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65166?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) to see if it resolves your issue.